# Ring buffer, 1 writer and N readers

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, c++11, design-patterns, concurrency

I need a sort of ring buffer (or some more appropriate data structure, in case) and an algorithm/pattern for handling the ring buffer in the following situation.

1 writer continuously producing real-time data has to be always able to either write into the first free "slot" (a slot which is NOT in the process of being read), or to wait until one slot is free for writing. Whenever the writer finishes to write the data into one slot, it can "commit" that slot for the readers.

At a given time, there may be N concurrent readers. Each reader should be always getting the most recent written data from the last committed slot in the ring buffer at the moment the read request is made, but must not read *the same data* more than one time. A reader should be waiting if no new data has been written and committed by the writer yet in one slot since its last read (think of a fast reader).

Note that 1 reader must not "consume" the data for another reader. In other words, two different readers may read the same data. And again, one reader may read the data from the same slot two or more times, but only if the writer wrote to that slot between the two read requests.

Note that the disruptor might not be adequate for my case (or I just failed to make it work as I want). The problem with the disruptor is that the writer might advance so quickly (compared to slower readers) that it may end up overwriting some slots while they are in the process of being read. In this case, the writer should be able to skip these "busy" slots until it  finds the first free slot (once written, it also has to publish that slot *only*), but the disruptor pattern does not seem to contemplate this situation. There is another issue with the sequence itself, which, in the disruptor implementation I am using, is an atomic integer, so it may overflow resulting in some undefined behaviour.

Do you have any idea? I'd appreciate solutions in modern C++, if you know any.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an out of the box solution for this problem (NB: this doesn't mean that there isn't one!) but if I was trying ti implement this using the c++11 facilities I'd be looking at something like the following:

- An array to hold the data
- A std::stack to hold the indexes of the elements that have been written
- A std::queue to hold the indexes fo the elements that have been read
- A mutex to control access to the stack.  So the readers and writer grab the Mutex before they pop/push onto the stack.
- A mutex to control access to the queue.  So the readers and writer grab the Mutex before they enqueue/dequeue onto the queue.
- A reader condition variable for readers to block on when the stack is empty
- A writer condition variable for the writer to block on when the queue is empty.
- To start enqueue all the indexs (size of your ring buffer) onto the queue.
- The writer gets the index and writes into the array and then pushes the index onto the stack and notifies the readers.
- The readers pop the indexes from the stack and when finished enqueue them onto the queue and notify the writer.
- An empty stack causes the readers to wait for the writer and an empty queue causes the writer to wait for the readers.

[A nice article on the C++11 concurrency features.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852594.aspx)

**EDIT** On further thought what this suggestion is trying to do is treat the slots in the array as a pool of resources.  The reader gets the resource, the index to the slot, and gives it back when its finished processing it.

**Updated Solution:**  As the number of slots is limited to a maximum of 8 I suggest that you keep the solution as simple as possible.  Make each slot responsible for its own state:

```
#include <atomic>
template <typename T>
class Slot {
   atomic_uint readers ;
   int iteration ;
   T data ;
}
```

Then create a std:vector of Slots and make the readers and writers iterate over the vector.

The writer needs to find a slot where `readers == 0` (and possibly with the minimum value of `iteration`) and when it does it needs to decrease the reader count and then check that the reader count is -1 to ensure a Reader didn't start reading inbetween the if and the decrement.  If it did then re-increment `readers` and start over.

The Readers iterate over the array looking for maximum `iteration` value that they haven't Read yet and where `readers >= 0`.  They then re-check the value of `readers` and if the Writer hasn't set it to -1 they increment it and start reading. If the Writer has started writing that slot then the Reader starts over.

Lets say the Writer has identified a slot as free and a Reader has decided it need to read the slot, there are 2 posibile ordersings and in both the Reader and Writer both back down and try again.

```
Execution       Writer                  Reader
1               readers == 0 
2                                       readers >= 0
3               readers--
4                                       readers++
5               readers == -1 is false
6                                       readers > 0 is false!
7               readers++
8                                       readers--


Execution       Writer                  Reader
1                                       readers >= 0
2               readers == 0 
3                                       readers++
4               readers--
5                                       
6               readers == -1 is false
7                                       readers > 0 is false
8               readers++
9                                       readers--
```

If the a Reader and the Writer do clash in this way neither gets access and both need to try again.

If your not comfortable with this approach then a Mutex and a lock/try_lock could be used, something like this inside the Slot class (NB: Can't run this through a compiler at present so may have syntax errors)

```
typedef enum LOCK_TYPE {READ, WRITE} ;
std::mutex mtx ;

bool lockSlot(LOCK_TYPE lockType)
{
    bool result = false ;
    if (mtx.try_lock()) {

        if ((lockType == READ) && (readers >= 0)) 
            readers++ ;
        if ((lockType == WRITE) && (readers == 0)) 
            readers-- ;
        result = true ;
    }
    return result ;
}

void unlockSlot (LOCK_TYPE lockType)
{
    if (mtx.lock()) {  // Wait for a lock this time

        if (lockType == READ) 
            readers-- ;
        if (lockType == WRITE)
            readers++ ;
    }
}
```

When/If a Reader runs out of work it can wait on a condition variable that the Writer can use to NotifyAll() the readers when new data is available.

Comment: it would not work as I want: "The readers pop the indexes from the stack and when finished enqueue them onto the queue and notify the writer. " . Many readers can share the same index. One reader cannot "steal" (by popping), as I said, one index to following readers (if a new index has not been pushed in the stack yet ).

Comment: @Martin - I'm not really sure what you mean by this.  You have a fixed number of slots and the writer has to wait for a free slot so how does a slot become free?  Do all the readers need to read the data in a slot or is there some other criteria?  Are readers allowed to read the data simultaneaously or sequentially or both?  I think you need to explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: A given reader must not read the same data twice. But given two readers A and B, say A read some input first. With your solution it is poped from the readers queue. Then B asks for data and cannot read what A just read. You need something to keep track of the readers (what did they already read?)

Comment: @Rerito : you got what I meant. That's why the problem is more difficult than it may appears. I wonder why there apparently are no out of the box solutions for this problem with 1 writer (real time) N readers which always get the latest possible data , and  the only constraints that the writer must not overwrite what's being read. (it's not possible to copy the data for "isolated reading" too, as the copy itself would be expansive)

Comment: @Jackson  Apart from what Rerito said, yes, readings may be concurrent, as I said.

Comment: I think we need better description of a free slot.  The trivial case is one that hasn't been written to but what are the rules about re-using slots?  A ring-buffer implies that the oldest slot gets re-used but the question says 'first free/available "slot" (or wait until one slot is free for writing)' which kind of implies any slot not being written to.  Also how many slots are there going to be, does the solution have to work with 10, 100 or thousands of them?

Comment: @Jackson "a free slot" means "any slot NOT being currently read by any readers". I 'll update the description.

Comment: @Jackson: the number of slots is very limited, say from 2 to 8, but it does not really matter...

Comment: Need clarifications: (__A__) While a reader was busy with slot 1, the writer committed slots 2 and 3. Shall the reader proceed directly to slot 3 (as it is  most recent), or still deal with slot 2? (__B__) A fast reader _A_ is on slot 3, a slow reader _B_ is on slot 1. Could a writer reuse slot 2?

Comment: @user58697:  Answer A: Yes, the reader will have to proceed with slot 3 (as slot 2 is obsolete). Answer B: Yes, the writer has to reuse slot 2, as it's the only option. This answers your question. I also add the following: in the case B, suppose slot 2 is "newer" than slot 1 and slot 3, it may well happen that slot 2 is accessed by any of the readers (once they have finished to read their current slots) before the writer has the time to "lock" and reuse it for writing.

Comment: @Jackson: can you elaborate "for maximum iteration value that they haven't Read yet" and how you would handle "iteration". There might be  at least one race condition, when you say "Readers then re-check the value of readers and if the Writer hasn't set it to -1 they increment it and start reading." Between the check and the increment, the writer might have set readers to -1.As an example of this, think of a possible race condition on slot 2 in case B in my answer to user58697 above. In this case you would end up having 1 (and possibly more)  Readers and the Writer on slot 2 at the same time.

Comment: The Writer will be updating the slots in an unpredicatable manner, so each time it writes to the slot it increases the iteration value. The Readers need to keep track of the iteration values they have read, this allows them to identify the largest value they haven't read and read it.

Comment: @Jackson: did you see the race condition I mentioned above?

Comment: @Jackson ok, forget the race condition I mentioned above, as it does not exist. I am going to implement this and let you know asap.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this same (if I understood correctly) problem a few years ago and I have a solution. A journal paper with the algorithms is accepted and I'll put a reference here as it gets published, but for now, I can direct you to the code.

First of all however, this is done in real-time, in C and (currently) possibly with a POSIX back-end (in user-space) or RTAI back-end (in either user or kernel spaces).

Second, a requirement of mine was that the writer is *never* blocked because of the users. That is, if a writer cannot find a free buffer, it overwrites the current data frame. I have also addressed this issue and my tests show that with small collaboration on the reader part, this is completely avoided.

Note also that the idea is similar to "Periodic Data Buffers"<sup>1</sup> and "Cyclic Asynchronous Buffers"<sup>2</sup>, although I came up with it on my own. They use atomic operations, while I use reader-writer locks. Furthermore, they don't provide a solution for "swap skips" as I mentioned above.

Finally, the writers and readers are not just periodic. The writers could be periodic or sporadic (run per request) and the readers could be periodic, sporadic or best effort.

You can find the writer implementation [here](https://github.com/maclab/skinware/blob/78d0932324fea479b3b7a09e0f24b2478d6fb955/skin/src/writer.c#L78) and the reader implementation [here](https://github.com/maclab/skinware/blob/78d0932324fea479b3b7a09e0f24b2478d6fb955/skin/src/reader.c#L51).

For completeness, I'll paste the comment with the basic algorithm for periodic writer and readers in multi-buffer mode:

```
Writer:

write_lock(cur)
loop {
         if last period no swap
                 try swap again
         write
         try while period left
                 write_lock(next)
                 write_unlock(cur)
                 cur = next
         wait period
}
unlock(cur)

Reader:

loop {
        if last is new
                b = last
        else
                b = cur
        read_lock(b)
        read
        read_unlock(b)
        wait period
}
```

On `write`, the writer also timestamps the data in the buffer. This is useful for the readers to know if the data is new or old.

The point regarding the buffer swap in writer is that it tries, until either successful or it nears the end of its period to swap buffers. This is done with `try_lock`ing all other buffers to see which is available (stopping on the first success/end of period) (no busy looping of course). Once this is done, it also tells (through shared memory, which could be the same as the one containing the data buffers), when it expects to swap buffers again, and also which buffer contains the newest data (`last`), and which buffer the writer is currently in control of (`cur`).

The readers then have a choice. If `last` contains new data, `read_lock` it and carry on with reading. If not, or if the reader can estimate that it cannot perform the read in time for the next buffer swap, it waits instead for `cur` to get unlocked. The real-time scheduler then wakes the reader up as soon as it can once the writer has unlocked it. If the system is not under heavy load, this means almost instantly.

For the reader to know whether it can perform the read in time or not, it keeps track of its average execution time in the cycles and uses that to check whether `current_time + my_execution_time > next_expected_swap`. In such a case, it can't perform the read in time, so it will wait instead on `cur` which is soon expected to get unlocked.

---

<sup>1</sup> "HIC: an operating system for hierarchies of servo loops", Clark, D., Robotics and Automation, 1989. Proceedings., 1989 IEEE International Conference on

<sup>2</sup> "HARTIK: A Real-time Kernel for Robotics Applications", Buttazzo, G.C., Real-Time Systems Symposium, 1993., Proceedings.

---

Note: while this library is designed mainly for robot skin data handling, you can essentially use it for any general writer-reader communication with the above properties.  Furthermore, pay attention that the master branch of the repository I pointed to contains an older version. The branch I pointed to, `skinware-2` has a much better and more feature-rich implementation.

Comment: thanks I need sometime to analyze your solution. I let you know asap.